# Regular expression to match part of word

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression for a contains type search on a set string. The values in my database are....

```
Price Override Report
Shorts And Overs Report
Import Status
```

In my application my user can pass in "REP", "REPORT" or "REPORTS" which I create a regular expression from and all of those should match the first two rows. I think the rule should be that at least three characters in the regular expression string are contained in the database row however the three values can be in any part of the string.

I've given it a crack but finidng it a bit tough. So far I have...

```
REP{0,1}ORTS{0,1}
```

but I don't think that is right.

Aprreciate your help

Comment: Your rule: `think the rule should be that at least three characters in the regular expression string are contained in the database row however the three values can be in any part of the string.` can not be solved by a regexp or more precisely by a regular grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression: [`REP(?:ORTS?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/yA0iI6/1)

Will match:

- REP
- REPORT
- REPORTS

---

Explanation:

```
REP      (?# match REP literally)
(?:      (?# start non-capturing group)
  ORT    (?# match ORT literally)
  S?     (?# optionally match S literally)
)?       (?# close optional non-capturing group)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^.*?(?:\bREP\b|\bREPORTS?\b).*$
```

Try this to match all line containing `REP` , `REPORT` or `REPORTS`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/5